# Calling hidden APIs in Android like "createCustomCaptureSession"

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, qualcomm

I want to use **createCustomCaptureSession** API to configure android camera in a specific mode. These APIs are hidden and can't be used with Android SDK.

**Any potential way to call this API using SDK/AOSP?**

PS: The **framework.jar** file on my device is at location *system/framework*.

Comment: Access to hidden APIs is being banned progressively. Many were banned in Android 9.0, and others are banned in Android Q.

Comment: You can try to bypass Android's hidden API restrictions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970137/bypass-androids-hidden-api-restrictions